# Using replica sets in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

With Mongoose, you can connect to replica set like so:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database,mongodb://username:password@host:port,mongodb://username:password@host:port?options...' [, options]);
```

How do you connect to an external MongoDB replica set with Meteor?

Comment: Have you referenced mongoose with require yet?

Comment: You explicitly used mongoose in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply export `MONGO_URL` with replicaSet configured. And it works pretty well. Make sure to use meteor version 0.6.4 or greater.

See my [article for configuring](http://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-replica-sets-with-meteor.html) it.